# How do I export data from An Object?

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to export an object called coffeeTree from a file called Coffee_Tree.js into a js file called coffee.js so I can grab data from the object. But, I keep getting this:

Uncaught ReferenceError: coffee is not defined
    at Coffee_Tree.js:2

This is the code I have so Far, I am still A js beginner, But I can't figure out what to do I changed the html type to module, but that didn't work.
Here's my code so far:

`Coffee_Tree.js`

```
export default coffeeTree = {
    refill: () => {
        coffee.isEmpty = false;
        console.log('refilled');
    },
    drink: () => {
        coffee.isEmpty = true;
        console.log('chug');
    },
    isEmpty: true,
}
```

`coffee.js`

```
import coffeeTree from './Coffee_Tree.js';

console.log(coffeeTree);
```

Again in the Console I just keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: coffee is not defined
    at Coffee_Tree.js:2
```

Comment: It says "coffee is not defined", you are clearly using a variable of that name, why do you think it should be defined?

Comment: `coffee.isEmpty = false`, problem : `coffee` isn't defined anywhere. Hence the error.

Comment: @Daniel Gomez The error says ```coffee``` is not defined in ```Coffee_Tree.js```. In your ```Coffee_Tree.js```, you have refill and drink. But those functions refer to object ```coffee```, for example on the line ```coffee.isEmpty = false;```. Coffee is not declared before in this file.

Comment: I know I'm just still really new at using JSON and objects, I've been trying to learn as I go along, because I feel it Sticks more In my head. I'm still learning How to build my own JSON data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

(1) use the proper variable name (either `coffeeTree` or `coffee` - pick one, don't use both)

(2) An expression exported as default *does not* get put into the current scope as an identifier. You're currently implicitly creating a global variable and running in sloppy mode. One of the main purposes of having a module system is to avoid global variables when possible. Use named exports instead so that the object can reference itself inside its methods, and without assigning to the global object:

```
export const coffee = {
    refill: () => {
        coffee.isEmpty = false;
        console.log('refilled');
    },
    drink: () => {
        coffee.isEmpty = true;
        console.log('chug');
    },
    isEmpty: true,
};
```

```
import { coffee } from './Coffee_Tree.js';
console.log(coffee);
```

(I'd also highly recommend using strict mode, if at all possible - if you read the error messages and try to debug them, it'll help you avoid these sorts of mistakes)